# Keras - Custom loss function with multiple output and different weights per output

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

I'm trying to train a network with multiple outputs, in the below code: the loss from X, Y logits are weighted equally in the loss function. I want X weighted twice than Y. I tried Loss weight when compiling the model, but seems nothing changed.

Note: I am new to keras and deep learning

```
def custom_loss_fn(labels, model_outputs):

# target
    a_target = labels['a_target']
    b_target = labels['b_target']

#predictions x,y

    x_logits, y_logits = model_outputs

# Here I apply sparse_categorical cross-entropy function for the outputs 

    x_loss = tf.keras.backend.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(
        a_target, x_logits, from_logits=True)

    y_loss = tf.keras.backend.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(
        b_target, y_logits, from_logits=True)

# Weights are equals for both outputs
    total_loss = (tf.reduce_mean(x_loss) + tf.reduce_mean(y_loss)) / 2

# when I tried to make x_loss Weighted twice  y_loss, performance degrades; did I do something wrong here? 
# total_loss = ((tf.reduce_mean(x_loss) * 2 ) + tf.reduce_mean(y_loss)) / 2

    return total_loss

train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="train_loss")
```